# Fat Free PHP framework, router breaks unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, fat-free-framework

If you follow the advice at the F3 site for setting up unit testing it fails. The example steps you through creating a file with F3 tests and says to save it in the root as test.php. So the url would be `http://localhost/test.php`. Well... this will never work because the router chokes on it. Where do I put it? What would I put in the router index.php file? Perhaps I'm tired or just stupid right now, but I don't see how to run this test.php file.

Thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to check out the dev branch of F3.

https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/tree/dev

It consists of the latest code and a whole bunch of unit tests (see the `app` folder). The thing about the docs is: they're not 100% up to date and the example about unit tests doesn't work with routes. It's just pure PHP to test your app's functions by calling the `test.php` which tests the code of `hello.php`

If your router really tries to look for `test.php` in its routes, then you have to fix your rewrite rules, because you missed to exclude existing files and folders. Here's the snippet for Apache.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: I _think_ I have those lines in htaccess. I'll have to double check when I get home. I'll checkout that dev branch too. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I _did/do_ have those lines in htaccess so I'm not sure what's happening there. I did a work-around that actually seems pretty good: I created a new UnitTest model and added methods named for each model I need to test. I put the test code in those methods. That routes fine and runs the tests.